# CSPRNG use on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: random, amazon-linux

I need to use a cryptographically strong (certification requirement), which is of high quality (pass industry standard randomness tests) reasonably performant (see below) PRNG.

Originally, I assumed it would run on the latest Ubuntu LTS, and planned to read from `/dev/urandom` since, according to my information, as of kernel version 5.18 it seemed to tick all the boxes.

Performance-wise, running `{ timeout --foreground 1s cat /dev/urandom; } | wc -c` on an M1 Mac (for reference) achieved ~450MB/s throughput, and I got similar results from an x86-64 Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS VM.

A C++ program that read 40kB chunks achieved an even higher ~1GB/sec throughput, but I could not run compile and run an executable on it (though I assume that the ratio between the shell command and executable would be similar).

However, it turned out that it will be deployed on Amazon Linux 2 (kernel version 5.10) running in a VM, which means that the [algorithmic](https://www.zx2c4.com/projects/linux-rng-5.17-5.18/) and [performance](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-getrandom-8450p) improvements to the RNG will not be available.

My questions are:

- Will `/dev/urandom` on kernel 5.10 running on a VM still satisfy the original requirements, that is: provide cryptographically strong pseudo-random numbers that also pass industry standard randomness tests with a throughput of at least 1MB/sec?

I did not have access to the environment in question, but trying several online shells with earlier kernel versions produced inconsistent results: on a couple of systems ([kernel 5.4](https://onlinegdb.com/wwf4VuUtys), and [kernel 5.15](http://tpcg.io/_L1QBQ0)) I got the same throughput from `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`, which according to my understanding implies the same quality, but on another system (also [kernel 5.4](https://onecompiler.com/bash/3zbzfc78c)), `/dev/random` blocked and gave results between 0-200B/s (that's *bytes*, without a prefix), suggesting that `/dev/urandom`'s quality was degraded (unless I misunderstood something).

However, according to [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-5.6-Random-Rework), "*with Linux 5.6 /dev/random behaves more like /dev/urandom now for polling RNG data in user-space. The changed behavior causes /dev/random to behave the same as /dev/urandom except for reads being blocked until the CRNG (the Linux cryptographic-strength random number generator) is ready. Meanwhile /dev/urandom will continue to serve its best data but never block.*", so the tests above with kernel 5.4 are probably not valid for this case.

So it *looks* like I might get away with it, but I'm not sure.

- If it turns out that using the random pseudo-files is not an option, what are the alternatives that would tick the checkboxes above?  Will OpenSSL's [RAND_Bytes](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/RAND_bytes.html) fit the bill?

Comment: in addition to urandom implementation, it's still possible to save/load random seed, run haveged, etc. so if you have doubts regarding the kernel ability to collect entropy in a virtualized environment, you can just add your own entropy to the mix. as for the performance, you'll just have to benchmark it yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand it, `/dev/urandom` was already backed by a *good enough* CSPRNG even in 5.4 (it was ported to use ChaCha20 [in **4.8**](https://git.kernel.org/linus/e192be9d9a30555aae2ca1dc3aad37cba484cd4a), with  *both* devices backed by the same CSPRNG).

The bigger focus of the later changes was not the improvements to the RNG itself (though plenty of those did occur) but the *recognition* that the CSPRNG was in fact good enough, and the resulting removal of the "blocking due to entropy accounting" behavior for `/dev/random`, specifically because it was agreed that the CSPRNG was good enough to not need it.

So in other words, yes, according to my understanding /dev/urandom on 5.10 will be as high-quality as `/dev/random`, **after** its CSPRNG has been initialized – though it does not provide userspace any indication whether that has happened or not.

A better choice might be the getrandom(2) syscall (available since 3.something), which appears to provide "best of both worlds" (aka the new 5.18 `/dev/random` behavior) – with 0 specified as flags, it will block if the CSPRNG is not yet ready, but will not block afterwards.

Though, a userspace CSPRNG will always be faster due to lack of context switching – it's *very* common to use `/dev/urandom` or `getrandom()` to seed e.g. the OpenSSL RAND_bytes() or whatever else your cryptography library of choice provides. (I believe modern OpenSSL 3.0 will call `getrandom()` automatically so you don't need to manually seed it.)

(Side note: I tested `pv /dev/urandom > /dev/null` on various nearby x86 servers, from Westmere to Comet Lake, plus a VPS on ARM64 Ampere Altra for good measure, and they **all** reach the same 300–400 MB/s.)

> /dev/random blocked and gave results between 0-200B/s (that's bytes, without a prefix), suggesting that /dev/urandom's quality was degraded (unless I misunderstood something).

I believe the whole point of the recent changes is the recognition that /dev/urandom's quality *doesn't* degrade if it's backed by a good CSPRNG, and that the accounting that /dev/random did was meaningless (hence its removal in 5.6).

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer!  I would appreciate a pointer to some "official" source that I can refer to.

Comment: I don't really have much in terms of sources, except for [e192be9d9a30](https://git.kernel.org/linus/e192be9d9a30555aae2ca1dc3aad37cba484cd4a) as the initial /dev/urandom CSPRNG switchover (note "we don't pretend to track entropy usage […] anymore"). (And the next commit being relevant to performance: [1e7f583af67b](https://git.kernel.org/linus/1e7f583af67be4ff091d0aeb863c649efd7a9112).) Finally, [30c08efec888](https://git.kernel.org/linus/30c08efec8884fb106b8e57094baa51bb4c44e32) for the v5.6 random-urandom merge that you found mentioned in Phoronix.